# SQL for mutual like

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
match
---
id person_1_id persona_2_id liked
9  1           2            true
10 1           3            false
11 2           1            true
12 2           3            true
13 3           1            false
14 3           2            false
```

`person_1_id` is the liker and `person_2_id` is the one being liked.

How would I query for the mutual likes for `person id = 1`? Meaning `person_1_id = 1` likes `person_2_id` and `persona_2_id` likes them back. The expected result would be a single row that contains `person_id = 2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a self-join :

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.person_1_id, t1.person_2_id
FROM mytable t1
INNER JOIN mytable t2 
    ON t1.person_1_id = t2.person_2_id 
    AND t1.person_2_id = t2.person_1_id
    AND t2.liked = true
WHERE t1.liked = true;
```

Or a correlated subquery with an `EXISTS` condition :

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.person_1_id, t1.person_2_id
FROM mytable t1
WHERE 
    EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM mytable t2 
        WHERE 
            t1.person_1_id = t2.person_2_id 
            AND t1.person_2_id = t2.person_1_id
            AND t2.liked = true
    )
    AND t1.liked = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

This query will give you the results you want. It looks for any person that `person_id` 1 likes who also likes them back:

```
SELECT persona_2_id
FROM match m
WHERE person_1_id = 1 AND
      liked = true AND
      EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM match m1
              WHERE m1.person_1_id = m.persona_2_id AND
                    m1.persona_2_id = m.person_1_id AND
                    m1.liked = true)
```

Output:

```
persona_2_id
2
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=27cd73c62a8f45a1fe1dc67656af1f25)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with exists clause

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.person_1_id, t1.person_2_id
from tbl t1
where exists (select null from tbl t2
  where t1.person_1_id = t2.person_2_.id and
     t1.person_2_id = t2.person_1_id and
     t2.liked = true
) and t1.liked = true;
```

If you just want to query for person_1_id = 1 then simply add `and t1.person_1_id = 1` to the end